# Programmatically creating company signature on OWA 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

Any advice on possible script hints or learning documentation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a built in tool for doing this - though there are a number of ASP and other type of tools that you can install.

Other people have written scripts to do work like this - here's one example of a [script which generates signatures](http://robwhitehouse.com/windows/script-auto-generate-outlook-signature/).

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether there's a tool or not, but I am wondering if you can accomplish this with Disclaimers, which you can have the Edge Transport server add to messages that address various criteria you set up.

This Technet article will start you in the right direction:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124352.aspx

Comment: The problem with disclaimers are that they're added without the sender seeing them so they might add duplication of signature information and so on - compared with scripts that sets up signatures for all the client access ways (Outlook, OWA aso).